# TLS v1.3 support in Java 7/Tomcat 7

Tags: ssl, tomcat7

I have an app that runs on Tomcat 7 using Java 7.
Is TLSv1.3 support available in Java 7?

It's an old app and don't want to upgrade.
If not, are there any alternatives without upgrading it to Java 8?

Thanks.

Comment: (1) use https://www.bouncycastle.org cryptoprovider(s) instead of 'standard' Oracle/Open ones (2) for clientside only, use a recent tcnative=APR built on OpenSSL 1.1.1 _if_ compatible with tomcat7 (I don't know) (3) don't actually support in Java/tomcat but for incoming put a TLS terminator in _front_ like httpd, nginx, haproxy, varnish, or even stunnel or socat and/or for outgoing a separate TLS originator like squid, fiddler/charles/etc, or stunnel/socat. (0) But this is not really a programming question or problem.

Comment: Thanks dave_thompson_085 for your insight and suggestions. I am not familiar with all of your suggestions. However, I will look into these. My situation is I need to communicate with a remote server via API the server provides and it only supports TLS v1.3.